# Strange IE7 borders behaviour

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

my website looks ok in all browsers expect for IE7 I have lot of issues with this browser. Below is the image with which I have problems :

[image]

I made a pagination which has a problem with IE7, the border bottom and top doesn't render, anyone knows why? here is my css mayber that will give you hint what is wrong?

```
div.Pager a {
    display:block:
    float:left;
    padding: 2px 6px;
    border: solid 1px #e6e7e8;
    margin: 0 2px 0 2px;
    text-align:center;
}

div.Pager a:hover {
    background-color:#437FC1;
    border-color:#437FC1;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

div.Pager{

    display:block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding:6px 0 6px 0;
    margin-top:2px;
}
```

Anyone had similar problems, perhaps another approach to this? basically inside Pager div there are some a tags which are links to page numbers. Thank you

**UPDATE:**

Here is what happens when all css has passed validation, when semi-columns replaced : ,

[image]

Its amazing how everything works well in ff and IE8 without even css being valid.. when it is valid it doesn't work in any browser in all of them it looks like in the picture above
Yes here is HTML

```
<div class="Pager">
<div class="Pager_left">
<span class="light"> Page:</span> 
<span class="current">1</span> 
<a onclick="return Page.goto(10);" href="#">2</a>
<a onclick="return Page.goto(20);" href="#">3</a>
<a onclick="return Page.goto(30);" href="#">4</a>
<a onclick="return Page.goto(40);" href="#">5</a>…
<a onclick="return Page.goto(10);" href="#">»</a>
</div><div class="Pager_right"/></div>
```

Comment: Why has my answer been un-accepted?

Comment: I uploaded a new photo .. what happens and explanation .. below UPDATE in my post

Comment: Right, don't assume that it's because of the validation that it has failed, your code needs more work to get it 100%, could you post the HTML for your pagination.

Comment: Having a wild guess, since I don't have an IE7 installed, try giving your elements heights/widths where you can, it sometimes troubles the old IE7

Answer (score 3):

First of all have you checked your CSS / HTML is valid?

The [border shorthand syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp) should be as follows, you are specifying style before weight, it should be weight before style:

```
border: 1px solid #e6e7e8; /* correct format */
```

This may send IE7 into quirks mode, possibly causing your problem.

Also your code here doesn't terminate your selector correctly, use a semicolon instead.

```
display:block: /* look here, you need a ; */
```

Comment: No change, doesn't mather which one goes first its remained same

Comment: Ok, have you applied the second change, adding a `;` instead of a `:` to your `display:block:` line?

Comment: Excellent! Remember, W3C CSS validator is your friend, bookmark this bad boy. http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: Sorry m8, I have updated the question .. didn't have the time to refresh until now ..

Comment: I haven't forgotten, will look when I have a spare 5 mins :)